# How to Implement the fault Contract/Exception handling in WCF and Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have already developed my application, which has more than a 1000 functions. Now I need to implement fault contracts or exception handling in Silverlight without changing these functions.

Is there any common method that I can implement in one place in the WCF service layer and in one place in the Silverlight Application?

I want to implement this because when any exception occurs in the WCF layer, it will not send the real exception message to silverlight.

Silverlight only gets a message like this:

> "Remote server not found..."

Real problem is i have already developed the system and now i need to implement the falultcontracts without changing too much or each function in Service layer.. so is there any method to create the falutcontract wrapper and place it over the WCF service Layer?

Comment: I've provided an answer, but pay close attention to the first bullet: how can the service respond with anything at all (fault or a normal response) if the Silverlight app cannot *find* it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear to me from the question what's going on in your case, but I can mention:

- If you get an exception in Silverlight that the "**Remote server not found...**" then you won't get any exception details no matter what you do in the service (how can the service respond with those details, if the Silverlight app can not *find* the service?).
- If you want to see exception details from the service in your app for debugging purposes, you can apply it to the entire service through the **[IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx)** property in the ServiceBehavior. This is considered a security risk (disclosing internal exception details) so it's not recommended for production.
- As far as I know **[FaultContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx) have to be set on the operations** themselves, and you have to be explicit when you throw them.

PS. Your real problem may be that you have over a 1000 functions in your service, that doesn't seem healthy. On the other hand, if they are generated functions it may turn out to be a mixed blessing as you may be able to generate some fault code as well?

Comment: Real problem is i have already developed the system and now i need to implement the falultcontracts without changing too much or each function in Service layer.. so is there any method to create the falutcontract wrapper and place it over the WCF service Layer?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about "wrapping fault contracts on the service", and explain in detail what you've tried and what you're after.